# Generalization of the Structure theorem for artinian rings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $A$ is a ring with only a finite set of prime ideals $p_1...p_n$ and moreover $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{k_i}=0$ for some k_i. Is $A$ then isomorphic to $\prod_{i=1}^nA_{(p_i)}$?

Comment: Exactly on how many examples did you try this on? :)

Comment: ti4: Did you ask this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/ring-with-finitely-many-prime-ideals-with-an-extra-condition-are-they-maximal ?

Comment: Did you mean to assume that $A$ was Artinian?

Comment: Mariano: Perhaps I should've added that I thought it was wrong but could'nt find a convincing counterexample :)

Comment: Hailong: Yes I did, it is almost the same question, only this is a little weaker perhaps.

Comment: Karl: No I did not, then it would be a standard theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Let $A$ be a DVR. It has two prime ideals: the maximal ideal $p_1=\mathfrak m\subset A$ and $p_2=(0)\subset A$. So, $p_1p_2=0$, but $A$ is not a product (of two local rings).

Comment: Perhaps I have missed something huge but in this example it seems to me that product will be the ring localized at m, i.e. itself multiplied by the trivial ring, is this not isomorphic to the original ring?

Comment: You probably need to think carefully about what it means to localize at the prime $(0)$. 